# CodeIgniter 3, controllers return 404 error, but not when set as default

Tags: controller, load, codeigniter-3

I've been using CI for a long time, but this is my first try with CI 3.0, and I've run into problems at the very beginning: I cannot make any controller load, but the default one, all the others return a "Not Found. The requested URL /index.php/xxxx was not found on this server."

To isolate the problem, I've built a very simple controller in "Test.php" file located at the application/controllers folder. This is the content of that file:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Test extends CI_Controller
    {

        public function index()
        {
            echo "OK";
        }

    }
```

Ok, so if I try http://example.com/index.php/test it fails, but if I set "test" as default controller in routes.php file, then loading home page properly shows "OK" on screen.

Please notice this is not related with htaccess redirection, I'm intentionally testing using 'index.php' in the URL to avoid that kind of issues, but just as a side note, it fails also if I remove the /index.php part.

Comment: Note: in case it's important:

- The server is a Raspberry Pi running raspbian.
- The host file in my PC points to that Raspberry Pi by adding example.com and www.example.com as entries in the hosts file and config file base_url is set to http://www.example.com/.
- PHP version 5.4.45-0+deb7u5

Comment: One more note: I've just installed a fresh CI 3.1.2 package and it happens the same, the default controller (welcome) loads if nothing but the domain specified in the URL, but if I add /index.php/welcome it fails to load

Comment: I am just setting this up myself and so far so good... Can you access any controllers directly on the pi using localhost?

Comment: Well I have setup a LAMP stack on my Pi with the same PHP you are using, with CI 3.1.2, rewrite active, both www and non www etc and I cannot simulate your issue as it "just works!". I just can't see how you are getting this issue! I'd be taking another walk through your setup.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what "It Fails to Load" means?

Comment: Try disabling your .htaccess by simply renaming it and see what that does?